# How to count likes/comments of a photo/post using new Facebook Graph API 2.1?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried for several hours to get the total number of likes/comments of a photo/post using the new Facebook Graph API 2.1 but I didn't find how to do it.

I am able to photo and post details through the API but it contains only an subarray with some likes and comments (ID/Name pair), but no the total number. Graph API Reference for `object/likes` mention a `total_count` field but is not able to found in API response.

Can you please suggest me a way to do it?

I am using latest Facebook PHP SDK 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this situation before. **Facebook Graph API Explorer**, in the **Fields** dropdown list, you can not find any field related to total_like or total_comment of a specific post ( via its object_id). That means Facebook Graph API does not support getting the total likes, comments of a specific post.

But, it support to get likes, comments data of a post via **likes, comments fields**. So by this way, you can get the entire data about likes, comments, therefore, you can get the total number of likes/comments.  This solution is not good, I think. I think in the near feature, Facebook Graph API support the fields total_likes, total_comments.

```
/object_id?fields=comments.limit(1000),likes.limit(1000)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this trick. Strange that API documentation is not updated.